# Issues of horizontal scroll bar. xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

The problem is in scroll bar, if i scroll to the 1st column of the data in the horizontal direction and then try to scroll in the 0th column of data virtically, the scroll automatically comes to the first position of the 1st column of data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Scrolled event code:

```
private async void 1stColScrollView_Scrolled;(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
  await rowScrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, e.ScrollY, false);
  await colScrollView.ScrollToAsync(e.ScrollX, 0, false);
}
private async void 0thColScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
  await dataScrollView.ScrollToAsync(0, e.ScrollY, false);
}
private async void 1thColScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
  await dataScrollView.ScrollToAsync(e.ScrollX, 0, false);
}
```

and call:

```
dataScrollView.Scrolled += 1stColScrollView_Scrolled;
rowScrollView.Scrolled += 0thColScrollView_Scrolled;
colScrollView.Scrolled += 1thColScrollView_Scrolled;
```

[image]

Comment: without knowing what your UI looks like or how its composed its impossible to give much concrete advice

Comment: You can see this image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T46Pg.jpg), when i scroll x,y,z value horizontally after that scroll Type value virtically, xyz value come to 1st position automatically. @Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause is the 0 in the `0thColScrollView_Scrolled` and the `1thColScrollView_Scrolled`. You need to keep the dataScrollView's ScrollY when it scrolls horizontally and keep the ScrollX when it scrolls vertically. Such as:

```
private async void 0thColScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
  await dataScrollView.ScrollToAsync(dataScrollView.ScrollX, e.ScrollY, false);
}
private async void 1thColScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
{
  await dataScrollView.ScrollToAsync(e.ScrollX, dataScrollView.ScrollY, false);
}
```